# Why assigning the arguments of a callback function to a new local variable?

Tags: javascript

Is it important, assigning the arguments of a callback function to a new local variable and then use them? For example:

```
$scope.$on('someEvent', function(event) { 
  var _data = event.data; 
  console.log(_data); //method 1
  console.log(event.data); // method 2
});
```

Some Javascript developers prefer to use `method1`. Is that because of performance or something?

Comment: It's just to reduce the size of the code written. If you have to write conditions on event.data , you will have to write event.data.xxx.length etc... and it's annoying to have to write the prefix (event.data.xxx), for example.

Answer (score 3):

The rule of thumb is to do it whenever it is more readable to do it. There is not much performance issues in javascript, unless you deal with none-optimized code. The hardest part is readability.

A scenario that comes up in my mind is if there is a generic callback function over an item:

**Version 1:**

```
$myMap.load(function(event) {
    setView(event.target.data.initial.x, event.target.data.initial.y);
    ...
    filterLabels(event.target.data.initial.filters);
});
```

**Version 2:**

```
$myMap.load(function(event) {
    var savedData = event.target.data.initial;
    ...
    setView(savedData.x, savedData.y);
    ...
    filterLabels(savedData.filters);
});
```

Personnally, I prefer to save parameters into variables as soon as I feel it is easier for an eventual reader to understand what is going on. I'd use it way more often for readability than for performance.

Comment: In fact, creating a new variable isn't expensive at all compared to what the cpu does to interprete javascript code on your machine to make it interact with your page. In fact, that process is probably the most expensive in most web systems, and that makes creating a new variable look like a free action. You may take it as well if this can be helpful in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Minification I think. If you assign the argument to a variable, the variable could be minified i.e. `a`, which reduce the size of the code. Only useful if you call the argument multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

in your example not important but that useful because change in this object will apply on all function that use this object .

```
function foo (obj)
{
obj.a+=1;
} 

var obj = {
a:1
} 
foo(obj);
foo(obj);
//obj.a=3;
```

Comment: when we pass object to  javascript function all change will be in the same object not local

Comment: when we call foo function first time obj.a=1; and we plus 1 then obj.a = 2;
when we call foo function second time we pass new object not obj.a=1; 
we pass obj.a=2;